# javascript variable not been assigned properly

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript and have started learning recently. I am not able to assign the variable to correct value. Below is the code:

```
person={
firstname: fnName,
lastname:"Doe",
age:50,
eyecolor:"blue"
}

var fnName=(function(){
    return 'John';
})();

console.log(person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.");
```

The output should be John is 50 years old. The jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/Fj6Xf/

Please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Define your function first then use it, [here][1] is a good explanation. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var fnName = function() {
    return 'John';
}

var person = {
    firstname: fnName,
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 50,
    eyecolor: "blue"
}

console.log(person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.");
```

That way the object "person" will know what fName is. Also you don't need your function to call itself when the code is first executed. Format your function like the code above.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use `fnName` before you assign a value to it.  Move the `var fnName =` line to before the `person=` line, like this:

```
var fnName=(function(){
    return 'John';
})();

person={
    firstname: fnName,
    lastname:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyecolor:"blue"
}

console.log(person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.");
```

Answer (score 2):

The trailing parenthesis make your function call itself immediately, but that's after you've created your `person` object - at the time of its creation, `fName` was undefined, hence your error.  Switch the order around.

```
var fnName=(function(){
  return 'John';
})();

  person={
  firstname: fnName,
  lastname:"Doe",
  age:50,
  eyecolor:"blue"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can write a class after that we can call a method through object. like this

```
function person() {
this.firstname = fnName;
this.lastname = "Doe";
this.age = 50;
this.eyecolor = "blue";
}

var fnName = (function () {
    return 'John';
})();

var obj = new person();

console.log(obj.firstname + " is " + obj.age + " years old.");
```

Answer (score 1):

first you are using function as argument so it should be

`var fnName = function(){return 'john'};`
and also you should also know the execution pattern of javascript that is person.fname will be undefined so insted of defining the function below your object define at the top and do not  invoke function instantly after defining that function  because you need to get the value not fnname not to invoke there only.

also the object should also not to be defined like that you have defined if you do so then it will throw an exception so to define an object it format is

```
    var objectname = {
      propertyname : propertyvalue,
      propertyname : propertyvalue,
      propertyname : {
        anotherpropertname : anotherpropertyvalue,
        anotherpropertname : anotherpropertyvalue
  }

    };
```

remember when you are on the last property then dont use comma as you can see in the above example. object can also have a value as a function.

in your first property of your object `person` insted of define a function fnName seprately you could also written as

```
var person = {
  firstname : function(){return 'john'}
};
```

another intresting thing is that window is also an object that is you can also define an object like this `window["person"] ={fanme:FnName, age:50}` and so on..